# What does this mean: Every element $\pmod{2^n}$ that is $1 \pmod 4$ is a power of $5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For example, consider $17$. Then $17 \pmod{2^n}$ for any $n$ is always $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, but $17$ isn't a power of $5$.

Just in case I have misunderstood anything, please see this [video](https://youtu.be/hYCp7ACy9RE?t=1325) where the claim is made.

Comment: 625=17 mod 32, and other powers of 5 work for mod 64 etc

Comment: Power of $5$, modulo $2^n$?

Comment: @Empy2: So we're talking about powers of $5 \mod 2^n$? In that case, $17$ isn't a counter example, since $17=5^4 \mod 2^4$?

Comment: Yes, it's powers mod $2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: for any power of $2$, say $2^n$, and any residue $0<k<2^n$ such that $k\equiv 1\pmod 4$, there is a value $r\geq 0$ satisfying
$$5^r\equiv k\pmod{2^n}.$$
Clearly these are all the values of $k$ (mod $2^n$) for which such a statement can be true, since $5^r\equiv 1\pmod 4$ for any $r$.

For example, with $k=17$ and, say, $n=5$ we get $5^4=625\equiv 17\pmod {32}$, and a (different) value of $r$ can be found which works for any given larger power of $2$. (If we were to take $n=6$ the first value which works is $r=12$, since $244140625\equiv 17 \pmod{64}$.)

Answer (score 1):

When $m\equiv (1(\bmod 4)\bmod 2^n$, it means we can write:

$$m=k2^n+ 4t+1$$

k can be $k=2^n$ ant t can be  $t=\frac{\sum {n\choose i}4^i\cdot 1^{n-i}}4$such that:

$$m=(2^n)^2 + \sum {n\choose i}4^i\cdot 1^{n-i}+1=(4+1)^n=5^n$$

This shows the condition, that is why numbers such as 17 or 33 . . . can not be condidates.